# New with tile map

Tags: c#, monogame

hello i am trying to create a map with tiles that allow me to place them singularly in specific areas on a map. as you see in this image

[image]:

The tiles are placed in specific areas using numbers, i am using Monogame on visual studio,i am having trouble finding methods/explanations on doing this, its not an easy question to answer because many options can be given, but anything will appreciated.

Edit:

also i am trying to place a tiles to make a road out of single tiles.

Comment: You need to add these as a group to your map, so do some error checking to make sure it is a valid placement, then copy the 2d array onto the map

Comment: hello, basically im a slow learner, and to a slow learner i have no idea what u meant by that. could u give some references some links explanations that would be helpful

Comment: A tile map is basically a 2d array, you need to modify this 2d array (of the tile map) to include the 2d array of tiles that creates your pipe. Any answer is too broad for stack overflow

Comment: well is there any way you could help me create this 2d array for the tile map.

Comment: Maybe im asking for too much. but its worth the ask

Comment: There are plenty of resources around about how to create 2d arrays or tile maps

Comment: @sedar i recommend you to edit your title to something more relevant, that you will write on google, similar to "How i build a map with tiles"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build this from a 2d array like below, the most important part is the **position** of the tile on drawing.

`x * texture.Width` makes sure that on x axis you draw the textures one after another.

`y * texture.Height` makes sure that you draw the textures line one below each other.

`tilesPosition[y][x]` contains the position (0 to 18 in your case) of the tile which will be drawn

```
var textures = new Texture2D[]
{
    Content.Load<Texture2D>("texture0"),
    // others
    Content.Load<Texture2D>("texture18")
}

int[][] tilesPosition = new int[][]
{
    new[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    // others
    new[] {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0},
    // others
    new[] {18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18}
};

for (int y = 0; y < tilesPosition.Length; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < tilesPosition[x].Length; x++)
    {
        var texture = textures[tilesPosition[y][x]];
        Vector2 position = new Vector2(x * texture.Width,y * texture.Height)
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

The iteration will look like below.

[image]

Comment: great looking code, how would i input a single tile across a road

Comment: @sedar you succeed making the array of tiles? Cab you give me more details about "input single tile across a road "?

Comment: well that mario was an example to learn more, but my road is like this in the picture, http://gyazo.com/78f97ea22e94d0cd48e3fbd29142e3c3 and i want the tile on the top left to be placed however i like on by one, but i do not know how to do that.

Comment: @sedar this in done in the same way as mario example, with very little additions. The most simple way to do it will be to consider for `0` the tile that is not road and for  `1` the tile that is road, and you build a 2d array with `1` and `0`. (be sure that the non road tile to be equal in size with the road part tile). Instead of 19 tiles, you have just 2. (different type of road can be added so you can end up with more than 2 type of tiles).

Comment: okay i will search how to write a 2d array with 1 and 0's  thank you so much

Comment: adricadar if i put the code you gave in how would i edit it to make the road:
http://gyazo.com/4a9b11dfc94e38eaf0bd3fedd837bb43 go on this image, im having trouble coding this since i dont have much knowledge coding.

Comment: can you make a picture similar with that you provided in in question, will be much easy to explain. (the picture to have the result, the matrix, and the tiles).